# Is there a way to force quotation of numbers in JSON 1.x Perl module?

Tags: json, perl

Test script

```
use JSON;
$\ = "\n";
my $big_number = '12345678901234567890123456';
print $big_number;
print objToJson([$big_number]);
```

Output (JSON 1.07, Perl 5.8.7)

```
12345678901234567890123456
[12345678901234567890123456]
```

Output (JSON 2.15, Perl 5.10.1)

```
12345678901234567890123456
["12345678901234567890123456"]
```

I'd like to have strings representing numbers being quoted when using JSON 1.x the same way they are being quoted when using JSON 2.x. Is there any way to direct JSON 1.x Perl module to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `AUTOCONVERT` to a false value, i.e.:

```perl
$JSON::AUTOCONVERT = 0;
```

Comment: Can I limit the scope of this setting somehow? The JSON library is used in *mod_perl* environment and I would like to avoid persistent changes to its configuration as there's existing code which might break.

Comment: Or create object like `new JSON(autoconv => 0);`