# Why do I get "Usage: JSON::XS::new(klass)" error?

Tags: json, perl

This line
`my $json = new JSON(autoconv => 0);  # <-- line X`
raises this error

```
Usage: JSON::XS::new(klass) at (...) line X
```

What's wrong?

It's a follow up to my question [Is there a way to force quotation of numbers in JSON 1.x Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7371335/)

Comment: Do not use die.net anymore, it's outdated. See [metacpan.org](https://metacpan.org) for module documentation, [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org) for core Perl documentation and [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/)/[he.net](http://man.he.net) for genereal man pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API for the [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) module [changed substantially](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON#INCOMPATIBLE_CHANGES_TO_OLD_VERSION) between [1.15](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-1.15/lib/JSON.pm) and 2.00.  Code written for JSON 1.x won't necessarily work with JSON 2.x.  In particular, the 1.x constructor took optional parameters.  The 2.x constructor takes no parameters; instead, you use mutator functions after construction.

If you must support both JSON 1.x and 2.x for some reason, you'll need to check if `JSON->VERSION < 2` (actually `JSON->VERSION < 1.99` if you count the development releases of the 2.x API) and have two versions of your code, one for the 1.x API and one for 2.x.

Comment: For reference: at http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm one can read *The new method in 2.x takes any parameters no longer. You can set parameters instead;* with the following example `$json = JSON->new->pretty;`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my $json = JSON::XS->new;
```

I don't see any `autoconv` anywhere in either [`JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) or [`JSON::XS`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::XS), but `JSON` does say this:

> $JSON::AUTOCONVERT
>
> Needless. JSON backend modules have the round-trip integrity.

Comment: I found information on `autoconv` option to JSON *new* constructor at http://linux.die.net/man/3/json which gives this example `my $json = new JSON (autoconv => 0, pretty => 1);`

Comment: That looks to be the documentation for an incredibly old verion of the `JSON` module, and definitely isn't the documentation for `JSON::XS`, which is what you're using.

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost, Type `perldoc JSON` to get documentation for your version of `JSON`

Comment: @CanSpice, He *is* using JSON and not JSON::XS. The error message says JSON::XS because JSON is a front-end for JSON::XS and JSON::PP. (I personally use JSON::XS directly. I don't see the point of possibly settling for JSON:PP.)

Comment: I am seeing the same error but in a bit of a different scenario.  I use JSON::XS, then I do $j = JSON::XS->new->allow_nonref; Then my $pscalar = $j->decode($json_str).  If I use it with perl, using cgi-script it works fine.  If I use it in mod_perl, it works when I make a GET request to the page, but fails with Usage: JSON::XS::new(klass) in the error.log when everything is the same except I use the POST method.  If I use JSON::PP it works fine in all cases.  I really want to use the faster XS module, but might have to go to JSON::Tiny.